# Loop for solving a number of non-linear equations with nleqslv in R

Tags: r, loops, nonlinear-functions

I have a problem in solving a number of non-linear equations with `nleqslv` in R in order to solve for a distance-to-default measure. This is my first R code, so I am still struggling with some problems. My code looks like this (miniaturized to a three-case-data.frame):

```
library("nleqslv")
D <- c(28000000, 59150000, 38357000)
VE <- c(4257875, 10522163.6, 31230643)
R  <- c(0.059883, 0.059883, 0.059883)
SE <- c(0.313887897, 0.449654737, 0.449734826976691)
df <- data.frame(D, VE, R, SE)

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  fnewton <- function(x){
    y <- numeric(2)
    d1 <- (log(x[1]/df$D[i])+(df$R[i]+x[2]^2/2))/x[2]
    d2 <- d1-x[2]
    y1 <- df$VE[i]-(x[1]*pnorm(d1)-exp(-df$R[i])*df$D[i]*pnorm(d2))
    y2 <- df$SE[i]*df$VE[i]-pnorm(d1)*x[2]*x[1]
    y
  }
  xstart <- c(df$VE[i], df$SE[i])
  df$VA[i] <- nleqslv(xstart, fnewton, method="Newton")$x[1]
  df$SA[i] <- nleqslv(xstart, fnewton, method="Newton")$x[2]
  i=i+1
}
```

My problem is, that my code only gives me one solution, meaning that my loop does not work properly in the first place. The loop should overcome the fact, that `fnewton` is a vector of length 2 in the first place, but my data (or my example) is a longer vector than 2. I tried some things but I cannot handle the problem, I think there is a simple solution for this, but I do not see my mistake.

Comment: In function `fnewton`, is `y1`,`y2` supposed to be `y[1]`,`y[2]`?

Answer (score 0):

There are some simple mistakes in code.

1) As mra68 commented, change y1, y2 in fnewton function to `y[1]`, `y[2]`.

2) remove last line `i=i+1`
   (Next `i` is automatically mapped by the line `for(i in 1:nrow(df)){`.)

3) (Optional) Initialize df with VA, SA specified.

Here's final working code:

```
library("nleqslv")
D <- c(28000000, 59150000, 38357000)
VE <- c(4257875, 10522163.6, 31230643)
R  <- c(0.059883, 0.059883, 0.059883)
SE <- c(0.313887897, 0.449654737, 0.449734826976691)
df <- data.frame(D, VE, R, SE, VA=numeric(3), SA=numeric(3))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){

  fnewton <- function(x){
    d1 <- (log(x[1]/df$D[i])+(df$R[i]+x[2]^2/2))/x[2]
    d2 <- d1-x[2]

    y <- numeric(2)
    y[1] <- df$VE[i]-(x[1]*pnorm(d1)-exp(-df$R[i])*df$D[i]*pnorm(d2))
    y[2] <- df$SE[i]*df$VE[i]-pnorm(d1)*x[2]*x[1]
    y
  }

  xstart <- c(df$VE[i], df$SE[i])
  df$VA[i] <- nleqslv(xstart, fnewton, method="Newton")$x[1]
  df$SA[i] <- nleqslv(xstart, fnewton, method="Newton")$x[2]
}
```

Comment: Inefficiency in this code when calling `nleqslv`. You only need to call it once and assign the result to a variable `z` e.g. like this `z <- nleqlsv(....)`. And then assign `z$x[1] and z$x[2]` to the appropriate rows of `df`. You are now calling `nleqslv` twice with identical starting values.

Answer (score 0):

The code by `skwon` can be made more efficient by defining the `fnewton` function once outside the for loop and by putting the variables `df` and `i` in the arguments. Like so

```
fnewton <- function(x,df,i){
  d1 <- (log(x[1]/df$D[i])+(df$R[i]+x[2]^2/2))/x[2]
  d2 <- d1-x[2]

  y <- numeric(2)
  y[1] <- df$VE[i]-(x[1]*pnorm(d1)-exp(-df$R[i])*df$D[i]*pnorm(d2))
  y[2] <- df$SE[i]*df$VE[i]-pnorm(d1)*x[2]*x[1]
  y
}
```

and then change the loop to this

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    xstart <- c(df$VE[i], df$SE[i])
    z <- nleqslv(xstart, fnewton,  method="Newton",control=list(trace=1), df=df,i=i)
    df$VA[i] <- z$x[1]
    df$SA[i] <- z$x[2]
}
```

If the function `fnewton` becomes more complicated you can also use package `compiler` to speed it up (a little bit).

Finally you really should test that `nleqslv` has in fact found a solution by testing if `z$termcd==1`. If not then skip the assigning of the `z$x` values. I'll leave that for you.