# R Looping nleqslv using mutate

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

Please refer to the discussion at [Loop for solving a number of non-linear equations with nleqslv in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582267/loop-for-solving-a-number-of-non-linear-equations-with-nleqslv-in-r?newreg=b74e640c1a3a4364989941a506bd5e09).

I am facing same problem when looping nleqslv using mutate. single value across all observation. Following is the code:

```
circle_circle_list1 <- mutate(
  circle_circle_list, 
  X3=(nleqslv(zstart, f2, jac=NULL, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, R1, R2, r))$x[1], 
  Y3=(nleqslv(zstart, f2, jac=NULL, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, R1, R2, r))$x[2])
```

`circle_circle_list1` has around 30 rows.
It runs `nleqslv()`, however only first row gets the right values for `X3` and `Y3`, rest all rows gets the copy of first rows's `X3` and `Y3`.

Comment: Welcome to *Stack Overflow*. It is customary to provide example data with your question to make your issue reproducible. Please consider [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), thanks.

Comment: We cannot run your insufficient and incomplete example. But why don't you just use the method described in the link you provide? BTW you only need to run `nleqslv` once  for each starting value as explained in the provided link.

Comment: Circle_circle_list is stores X,Y, R of a 2 circles. with mutate & nleqslv I am trying to calculate third circle's X,Y,R that touches these 2 circles. it runs just fine using forloop as for(i in 1:nrow(circle_circle_list)) and running nleqslv inside but gives problem when used with mutate, where I am trying to compute column level values X3, Y3 and adding to datframe circle-circle-list using mutate.